# Check constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three  tables a,b and c and need to add a constraint  like below for checking the data integrity

The below is wrong but I need help in enforcing the below condition.

```
ALTER TABLE [a]
ADD CONSTRAINT  UOMGROUPIG CHECK UNITOFMEASURID IN (SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=1 )

ALTER TABLE [c]
ADD CONSTRAINT  UOMGROUPIG CHECK UNITOFMEASURID IN (SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=2 )
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I am actually checking for the records available there  (SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=2 ) this could return as  4 , 78,43,1  so the column UOMGROUPIG  should allow these values alone.

Comment: Can't you use a foreign key for that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is `WHERE UOMGroupId=1` condition, I believe this eliminates the use of a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

A scalar valued function like this works for your example, you can easily modify it and create your second constraint:

```
CREATE FUNCTION your_schema_name.udf_Check1(
    @UNITOFMEASURID INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @returnValue BIT = 0

    SELECT  @returnValue = CASE WHEN COUNT(UnitOfMeasureId) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    your_schema_name.b 
    WHERE   UOMGroupId=1
    AND     @UNITOFMEASURID = UnitOfMeasureId

    RETURN @returnValue

END
GO

ALTER TABLE [a] 
ADD CONSTRAINT UOMGROUPIG 
CHECK (your_schema_name.udf_Check1(UNITOFMEASURID) = 1)
GO
```

Here is the example: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f23e/3/0)**

Comment: @ivanThanks I am actually checking for the records available there  (SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=2 ) this could return as  4 , 78,43,1  so the column UOMGROUPIG  should allow these values alone.

Comment: You're welcome. I understood your check constraint as if you wanted any value that was getting inserted into `a.UNITOFMEASURID` to be already present in `b.UnitOfMeasureId` and `b.UOMGroupId` is required to be 1. For instance `UNITOFMEASURID` with value 111 can only be inserted into `a` if there is a row in `b` where `b.UnitOfMeasureId=111` and `b.UOMGROUPIG=1`, was that right?

Comment: OK, my answer should work that way, you can try the SQL Fiddle example that I added to the answer. If it's not working correctly, post some sample data and expected output (some rows from `b` and some rows that should and shouldn't be allowed to be inserted into `a`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write query within Check constraint. Instead you can call user defined function.

You can use same function in both constraints by passing `@UOMGroupId` value along with UNITOFMEASURID.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFnctn(@UNITOFMEASURID int, @UOMGroupId int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
    if exists(SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=@UOMGroupId 
    and UnitOfMeasureId = @UNITOFMEASURID)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END

     RETURN 0; --missed this line
END;


ALTER TABLE [a]
ADD CONSTRAINT  UOMGROUPIG CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn(UNITOFMEASURID, 1)=1);
ALTER TABLE [c]
ADD CONSTRAINT  UOMGROUPIG CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn(UNITOFMEASURID, 2)=1);
```

Comment: Thanks I am actually checking for the records available there  (SELECT UnitOfMeasureId FROM b  WHERE UOMGroupId=2 ) this could return as  4 , 78,43,1  so the column UOMGROUPIG  should allow these values alone.

Comment: It throws an error Msg 455, Level 16, State 2, Procedure CheckFnctn, Line 8
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.

Comment: @ArunKumar: Missed else condition. See my update. Function must return a value, so added `RETURN 0` if record is not found.